# Angular JS validation after form element value change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

This is my first post here, and I wonder if you guys can help me.

Right now I'm working with AngularJS but I have an issue with a validation, as you can see in this link http://jsfiddle.net/ANxmv/1488/

The problem is when you click on the "Set" button, the input field change with a default email, but angular is not triggering the validation.

But if you click on the input (without erasing it) and modify it, the validator works fine.

Is there a way to validate without manipulate the input?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<form name="form" ng-app>
    <div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email address</label>
        <p>Is it valid? {{form.email.$valid}} </p>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" name="email" value="123@has.com" ng-model="email" required/>
                <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
                <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>        
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" onClick="set()" >Set</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
var set = function(){
    var $form_1 = document.forms['form'];
    $form_1.elements["email"].value = "123@default.com";
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not working because you are accessing/changing its value directly from the element so angular is not aware of that change so binding is not working instead make a use of `$scope` so that angular can track the changes.

**HTML**

```
<form name="form" ng-app="jsfiddle">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl" class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted && form.email.$invalid]">
        <p>Hello {{email}}!</p>
        <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email address</label>
        <p>Is it valid? {{form.email.$valid}} </p>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="email" name="email" value="123@has.com" ng-model="email" required/>
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
            <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="set()" >Set</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('jsfiddle', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.set = function(){
    $scope.email = "123@default.com";
  };
});
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/qms0931z/2/)

Comment: Thank you!, that was what I was specting to do.